# TypeError: cell is undefined[Learn More] jspdf.plugin.autotable.js:690:17

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am converting a table to pdf, if I put the pdf into portrait then the PDF gets generated with no issues.

However the table is quite wide so I need to switch it to landscape, as soon as I do I receive the following error:

> TypeError: cell is undefined[Learn More] jspdf.plugin.autotable.js:690:17

Sadly I can't share the table as it is confidential work (hence the local pdf creation) but here is the script I am using.

```
    $('#btnExportPDF').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                let source = document.getElementById('iframeReport').contentWindow.document.getElementById('tblReport');
                $('#divHiddenTable').html(source.outerHTML);
                console.log(source);

                let doc = new jsPDF({format: 'a4', unit: 'pt', orientation: 'l'});//change l to p and it works
                console.log('PDF Obj');

                doc.autoTable({html: '#tblReport'});
                console.log('PDF autoTable');
                doc.save("RegionalDirectorsWriteOffReviewExport.pdf");
                console.log('PDF save');
    });
```

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/3.0.9/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
```

After some more investigation, it appears that if I remove the OFFICE 3 section from the table below it works, but with it in it doesn't.

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="tblReport">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Client
                            Code</th>
                        <th>Client
                            Partner</th>
                        <th>Client
                            Name</th>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        <th align="center">Billed</th>
                        <th align="center">WIP
                            W/O</th>
                        <th align="center">Profit/
                            Loss</th>
                        <th>Recovery</th>
                        <th>Comments</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr class="OfficeHeader">
                        <th colspan="9">City 1</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>123456</td>
                        <td>NAME</td>
                        <td>COMPANY </td>
                        <td>WHOAMI</td>
                        <td class="text-right">2,069.58</td>
                        <td class="text-right">4,609.66</td>
                        <td class="text-right">-2,540.08</td>
                        <td class="text-right">44.89</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>45384</td>
                        <td>NAME</td>
                        <td>COMPANY 2</td>
                        <td>WHOAMI</td>
                        <td class="text-right">195.00</td>
                        <td class="text-right">4,559.74</td>
                        <td class="text-right">-4,364.74</td>
                        <td class="text-right">4.27</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>852136</td>
                        <td>NAME</td>
                        <td>COMPANY 3</td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td class="text-right">600.00</td>
                        <td class="text-right">3,109.00</td>
                        <td class="text-right">-2,509.00</td>
                        <td class="text-right">19.29</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>111</td>
                        <td>NAME</td>
                        <td>COMPANY 4</td>
                        <td>WHOAMI</td>
                        <td class="text-right">0.00</td>
                        <td class="text-right">1,677.50</td>
                        <td class="text-right">-1,677.50</td>
                        <td class="text-right">0.00</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>123654</td>
                        <td>NAME</td>
                        <td>COMPANY</td>
                        <td>WHOAMI</td>
                        <td class="text-right">0.00</td>
                        <td class="text-right">1,169.75</td>
                        <td class="text-right">-1,169.75</td>
                        <td class="text-right">0.00</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="OfficeFooter">
                        <td colspan="4" class="text-right">Office Totals</td>
                        <td class="text-right"><div class="double-border">2,864.58</div></td>
                        <td class="text-right"><div class="double-border">15,125.65</div></td>
                        <td class="text-right"><div class="double-border">-12,261.07</div></td>
                        <td colspan="2"><div class="pagebreak">&nbsp;</div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="OfficeHeader">
                        <th colspan="9">City 2</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>A-569</td>
                        <td>NAME</td>
                        <td>COMPANY </td>
                        <td>WHOIZYOU</td>
                        <td class="text-right">2,175.00</td>
                        <td class="text-right">4,361.72</td>
                        <td class="text-right">-2,186.72</td>
                        <td class="text-right">49.86</td>
                        <td>Overrun against a thing that we don't know so can't put here</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>D/6666</td>
                        <td>NAME</td>
                        <td>COMPANY</td>
                        <td>WHOIZTHIS</td>
                        <td class="text-right">1,300.00</td>
                        <td class="text-right">2,371.01</td>
                        <td class="text-right">-1,071.01</td>
                        <td class="text-right">54.82</td>
                        <td>Taken on from previous prtner and manager</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="OfficeFooter">
                        <td colspan="4" class="text-right">Office Totals</td>
                        <td class="text-right"><div class="double-border">3,475.00</div></td>
                        <td class="text-right"><div class="double-border">6,732.73</div></td>
                        <td class="text-right"><div class="double-border">-3,257.73</div></td>
                        <td colspan="2"><div class="pagebreak">&nbsp;</div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="OfficeHeader">
                        <th colspan="9">OFFICE 3</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>GFDGDFGF</td>
                        <td>NAME</td>
                        <td>COMPANY </td>
                        <td>WHO</td>
                        <td class="text-right">2,910.00</td>
                        <td class="text-right">8,385.21</td>
                        <td class="text-right">-5,475.21</td>
                        <td class="text-right">34.70</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>KJHKJHKJ</td>
                        <td>NAME</td>
                        <td>COMPANY Limited </td>
                        <td>WHO</td>
                        <td class="text-right">2,310.00</td>
                        <td class="text-right">4,733.76</td>
                        <td class="text-right">-2,423.76</td>
                        <td class="text-right">48.79</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>OIOUIO</td>
                        <td>NAM,E</td>
                        <td>COMPANY</td>
                        <td>WHOZ</td>
                        <td class="text-right">0.00</td>
                        <td class="text-right">2,110.25</td>
                        <td class="text-right">-2,110.25</td>
                        <td class="text-right">0.00</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="OfficeFooter">
                        <td colspan="4" class="text-right">Office Totals</td>
                        <td class="text-right"><div class="double-border">5,220.00</div></td>
                        <td class="text-right"><div class="double-border">15,229.22</div></td>
                        <td class="text-right"><div class="double-border">-10,009.22</div></td>
                        <td colspan="2"><div class="pagebreak">&nbsp;</div></td>
                    </tr>

                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                    <tr style="height: 2px !important; overflow: hidden !important;">
                        <td colspan="4"><div style="line-height: 2px !important; height: 2px !important; font-size: 2px !important; overflow: hidden; !important;">&nbsp;</div></td>
                        <td colspan="3"><div style="line-height: 2px !important; height: 2px !important; font-size: 2px !important; background-color: #e7ebee;  overflow: hidden !important;">&nbsp;</div></td>
                        <td colspan="2"><div style="line-height: 2px !important; height: 2px !important; font-size: 2px !important; overflow: hidden; !important;">&nbsp;</div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" class="text-right">AVG</td>
                        <td class="text-right">1,319.98</td>
                        <td class="text-right">3,526.59</td>
                        <td class="text-right">-2,206.61</td>
                        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" class="text-right">Totals</td>
                        <td class="text-right"><div class="double-border">27,719.58</div></td>
                        <td class="text-right"><div class="double-border">74,058.42</div></td>
                        <td class="text-right"><div class="double-border">-46,338.84</div></td>
                        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
```

example JSFiddle https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.css